# Calculating the mass in g of a molecule

Tags: molecules, mole

If I have the amount of the molecule in moles, how do I calculate the mass of an individual molecule?

For example, if the molecule was water?

Answer (score 2):

The "amount of molecules in moles", such as 7 moles, provides no information concerning the mass of an individual molecule.

This is like asking, "if I have the amount of eggs in dozens, how do I calculate the mass of an egg?"

Comment: Can you really not? :O

So if I knew I had one mole of water molecules, then 2.02g of the 18.01g would be hydrogen atoms. If I divide this by $6.02\times10^{23}$ wouldn't I get the mass of a H atom?

Comment: Firstly, the question doesn't say anything about atoms, just "the mass in g of the a molecule" and "the mass of an individual molecule".  Secondly, your comment is not using the amount of molecules in moles to calculate anything.  Instead, it is adding additional information, that the substance is water, and assumptions about the chemical structure of water.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you're trying to calculate the mass of a water molecule.  Water has a molecular weight of $18\:\mathrm{g/mol}$.  In a mole of water there will be Avogadro's number of molecules ($6.02\cdot 10^{23}\:\mathrm{molecules/mol}$).  Therefore, $$\text{mass of a water molecule} =  \frac{18}{6.02 \cdot 10^{23}} = 2.99 \cdot 10^{-23}\:\mathrm{g/molecule}$$